# Batch program to replace a string (having special characters) in a file?

Tags: batch-file, replace

My search string is :' property name="yes" value="d:/xyz/logs"/> '

My replace string needs to be : property name="yes" value="D:/xyz"/>

how to replace , when i have double quotes as part of the string i want to search and replace ???

Comment: You should show more from your file. Are there double quotes in the properties too?

Answer (score 0):

`set name=%name:d:/xyz/logs=D:/xyz%`  - Have you tried this?To escape `>` use `^>`.

Comment: i need to search the entire string property name="yes" value="d:/xyz/logs"/> ', as there are other places in file where i have 'd:/xyz/logs' but i do not want to replace them. I wan to replace only for property name = "yes".

Comment: are they on separate lines?

Comment: yes! there are multiple places (associated with different property names) on file where the string appears.

Comment: as you are processing .xml file it's better to use a .vbs script that you can call via bat : http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-replace.html .There is no a good way to process files that contains `!` in batch.